# Need help writing a function to sort an object of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting

What I am trying to do is sort an Object that includes only properties that are arrays. I am trying to sort it based on the length of the arrays. The reason I am trying to do this is so that I Object.keys() will provide a list of all names in the right order. This is my code: (I know its wrong, I cant think rn for some reason but this was my attempt.)

```
function sortSetsByAmount(SETS, callback) {
let n = {};
for (let i = Object.keys(SETS) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    let biggestSets = [];
    for (let j = Object.keys(SETS); j >= 0; j--) {
        if (SETS[Object.keys(SETS)[i]].length > biggestSets.length) {
            biggestSets = SETS[Object.keys(SETS)[i]];
        }
        if (j == -1) {
            n[Object.keys(SETS)[i]] == biggestSets;
        }
    }
}
callback(n);
```

}

Comment: I guess you mean `let i = Object.keys(SETS).length - 1`. Also you can not sort an Object's properties.

Comment: For example, what should be input and that the output?

Comment: You can set it in the right order right? Like {"key name":["key"], "key name 2":["key 2"]} can be put in a different order

Comment: @Smiranin For example: {730:[array with lots of arrays in it], 500: [array with lots of arrays in it]}. Output: {500: [array content], 730: [array content]. (If the array of 500 has more arrays in it than the array 730)

Comment: @timgfx Have you ever taken a look at the built-in `Array.prototype.sort` api?https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @Xlee yes, but that is only for arrays, in this case I am trying to sort and the arrays in an object, so its basically sorting an object

Comment: @timgfx Nothing different, instead of manual sorting inefficiently(as what you did ),  why not just get sorted keys by `Object.keys(SETS).sort((k1, k2) => SETS.k1.length - SETS.k2.length)`.

Comment: @Xlee thanks for helping, but that way SETS.k1 already gives an error saying it's undefined. What do k1 and k2 refer to? And should I be be defining those somehow and did I do something wrong? I don't really get the mozilla reference page explanation on that, but thanks!

Comment: @Xlee nvm, I fixed it by using SETS[k1] and SETS[k2] Instead, thank you!

Comment: @Xlee thanks but I dont think i need that. I will just use the sorted array as index for selecting the arrays :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In summary, you can **shallow clone** the original object to a new object with **sorted** keys:

```
Object.keys(SETS)                                               // key array of the original object
      .sort((k1, k2) => SETS[k1].length - SETS[k2].length)      // sort the keys compared by SETS[key] length
      .reduce((cloneObj, k) => ({...cloneObj, k: SETS[k]}), {}) // shallow clone to a new object
```